# Android Bluetooth connection Using RFCOMM using Insecure doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

Am using Bluetooth RFCOMM for connecting number of devices and transfer data between them, Used RFCOMM socket in INSECURE way, so i don't need to pair before connecting.

The problem is, I get a list of devices used thread for each devices for connection, After connection am sending a string data, It connects but data transfer doesn't happens all the time.

For connecting i need to use UUID and the UUID should be common on all devices, and i need to change this every time while i running newly.

I used the same code of google bluetooth chat [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

```
   private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothDataService.STATE_CONNECTED:

                        sen();  //After connecting am sending messaage
                        break;
                    case BluetoothDataService.STATE_CONNECTING:

                        showToast("connecting");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothDataService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        showToast("Listenining");
                        break;

                    case BluetoothDataService.STATE_NONE:
                        //setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        showToast("not connected");
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                tv2.setText(readMessage); //getting the message from sender and printing it in textview.


                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
               String mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                showToast("connected to -"+mConnectedDeviceName);
                sen();
                if(flag) {   // used handler for connecting next deivces in the list of devices 
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            val++;
                            Log.e("type++",String.valueOf(val));
                          //  mBlueDataService.stop();
                        }
                    }, 5000);

                }
                if(flag && temp>1) {
                    nextDevice.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                 //   mBlueDataService.start();
                            if (val <= (temp - 1)) {
                                Log.e("type", "" + String.valueOf(val) + "--" + String.valueOf(temp)+"---"+mDeviceList.size());
                                try {
                                    connectDevice(mDeviceList.get(val));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("type=",e.getStackTrace().toString());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 7000);
                }



                break;

        }
    }
};
```

1. If i connected only two devices, It gets connected and send and
   receive data perfectly for the first time, If i run it once again it
   doesn't works.

   2. If i connects more then two devices it gets connected to all the devices in the list one by one BUT no data transfer happens..

I used the same services class from google BluetoothChat [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java)